# R Topic Modeling avoiding create_matrix

Tags: r, topic-modeling

Normally when topic modeling I use something along the lines of:

```
matrix <- create_matrix(cbind(as.vector(lda_data)), language="english", removeNumbers=TRUE, weighting=weightTf)
k <- 20 #Hardcoded temp value
lda <- LDA(matrix, k, method = "Gibbs", control = list(iter = 1000, burnin = 1000))
Terms <- terms(lda, 20)
```

But with a mid sized data set (3.2M rows) I get the following error calculating the matrix:

```
Warning message:
In nr * nc : NAs produced by integer overflow
Error in as.matrix(textColumns) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': Error in vector(typeof(x$v), nr * nc) : vector size cannot be NA
```

Is there a different library/approach that avoids this error? (The code works fine on small data sets)

Alternatively, when using a TermDocumentMatrix as the matrix for the LDA, my resulting Terms are entirely numerical, is there a way to strings (words) instead?

Comment: Don't know how to solve that paritcular problem in R, but if you are stuck you could try using a different topic modeling application. If you know Java take a look at Mallet, if you know Python look at Gensim. There is also the original LDA implementation by Blei written in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used an alternate approach to creating the matrix which works on the large data set:

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(donation_message, 
                          control = list(stemming = TRUE, stopwords = TRUE, 
                          removeNumbers = TRUE, removePunctuation = TRUE))

dtm <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.99)
rowTotals <- apply(dtm , 1, sum) #Find the sum of words in each Document
dtm   <- dtm[rowTotals> 0, ] #Remove all docs without words

k <- 20 #Hardcoded temp value
lda <- LDA(dtm, k, method = "Gibbs", control = list(iter = 1000, burnin = 1000)) #seed = 1000, thin = 100
Terms <- terms(lda, 20)
```

Comment: This approach simply reduces the size of the matrix by eliminating information from it. For example, removing sparse terms via `dtm <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.99)`. It doesn't solve OP's problem, if they want have a matrix and don't want to resort to removing sparse terms, stop words, etc (i.e., massive information loss).